# ORACLE dynamic query where clause based on column value

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have checked SO questions / responses for dynamic queries, discussing about CASE.. WHEN.. END.  But, please note that am new to Oracle, and could not find a proper solution for my use case. Thanks.

I have the following sample data, and based on a condition I need to get an EMPID for a given department:

```
DEPTNO  EMP_ID  IS_PRIMARY  SDATE   EDATE     IS_ACTIVE
11250   12321   Y         01-Jan-17 29-Apr-18   N
11250   12343   N         01-Jan-17 29-Apr-18   N
11250   87653   N         16-Jul-18 31-Dec-00   Y
```

Primary validation is return the EMPLOYEE ID for the department (11250), if IS_PRIMARY = 'Y' & IS_ACTIVE = 'Y'.  If IS_PRIMARY is 'N', then return the employee id, where IS_ACTIVE = 'Y', (which means based on query I should get employee id 87653).

I have tried the following query, but am getting all the records, can someone please help me.

```
select EMP_ID from employee a where (a.deptno='81B11' and a.is_primary = 'Y') or (a.deptno='81B11' and a.is_active='Y' and a.is_primary_territory='N');
```

Thanks

Comment: For your sample data, `IS_PRIMARY = 'Y' OR IS_ACTIVE = 'Y'` works.  Is that sufficient for your actual solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` to check if primary and active employees exist for the department. If they do only select them. If they don't exists just select the active ones.

```
SELECT e1.emp_id
       FROM employee e1
       WHERE e1.deptno = '81B11'
             AND (EXISTS (SELECT *
                                 FROM employee e2
                                 WHERE e2.deptno = e1.deptno
                                       AND e2.is_primary = 'Y'
                                           e2.is_active = 'Y')
                  AND e1.is_primary = 'Y'
                  AND e1.is_active = 'Y'
                   OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                         FROM employee e2
                                         WHERE e2.deptno = e1.deptno
                                               AND e2.is_primary = 'Y'
                                                   e2.is_active = 'Y')
                      AND e1.is_active = 'Y');
```

Comment: Thank you stickybit for the code sample, it was useful. Will accept your answer.